# Architecturing an ML API in Django

Tags: python, machine-learning, django-rest-framework

I work on a project for our clients which is heavily ML based and is computationally intensive (as in complex and multi-level similarity scores, NLP, etc.) For the prototype, we delivered a Django RF where the API would have access to a database from the client and with every request at specific end-points it would literally do all the ML applications on the fly (in the backend).

Now that we are scaling and more user activity is taking place in the production, the app seems to lag a lot. A simple profiling shows that a single POST request could take upto 20 secs to respond. So no matter how much I optimize in terms of horizontal scaling, I can't get rid of the bottleneck of all the calculations happening with the API calls. I have a hunch that caching could be a kind of solution. But I am not sure. I can imagine a lot of 'theoretical' solutions but I don't want to reinvent the wheel (or shall I say, re-discover the wheel).

> Are there specific design architectures for ML or computationally intensive REST API calls that I can refer to in redesigning my project?

Comment: lol of cource move ML functionality to backend and present results only or it must be like that but p2p distributed

Comment: @snamef my bad. I've updated the question. Actually yes, we process the functionality in the backend... but at every API call.

Comment: then, also try to hash resulst andmove calculations to GPU, or at least on native code, not Python code

Answer (score 2):

Machine learning & natural language processing systems are often resource-hungry and in many cases there is not much one can do about it directly. Some operations simply take longer than others but this is actually not the main problem in your case. The main problem is that the user doesn't get any feedback while the backend does its job which is not a good user experience.

Therefore, it is not recommended to perform resource-heavy computation within the traditional HTTP request-response cycle. Instead of calling the ML logic within the API view and waiting for it to finish, consider setting up an asychronous [task queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#task_queue) to perform the heavy lifting independently of the synchronous request-response cycle.

In the context of Django, the standard task queue implementation would be [Celery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celery_(software)). Setting it put will require some learning and additional infrastructure (e.g. a Redis instance and worker servers), but there is really no other way to not to break the user experience.

Once you have set up everything, you can then start an asynchronous task whenever your API endpoint receives a request and immediately inform the user that their request is being carried out via a normal view response. Once the ML task has finished and its results have been written to the database (using a Django model, of course), you can then notify the user (e.g. via mail or directly in the browser via [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websockets)) to view the analysis results in a dedicated results view.